# Can "muelle" be the 3rd person singular of a verb?

Tags: gramática

"Muelle" comes up in a poem by the Mexican poet Pedro Serrano. The context is: "...el conejo en el césped húmedo /
salta y muelle su curvatura".

Can "muelle" be the 3rd person singular form of "mollir" or "mullir" in Mexican Spanish? "Mullir" is defined as "ahuecar una cosa con las manos par que esté blanda y esponjosa", which would seem to make some sense, but the 3rd person sg. form is given as "mulle" everywhere I've looked.

I am not familiar with Mexican Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

*mollir* is a verb, though somewhat old-fashioned:

> **mollir**
>   Del lat. *mollīre.*
>   **1.** *tr.* *desus.* Poner blando.

Although the RAE doesn't provide conjugations for *mollir*, it's clear it comes from *muelle*, which indicates a stem-changing vowel.  Some of the *-ir* verbs permanently adopted the *e→i* and *o→u* in their stem, hence the more modern form *mullir*.

As a guess, what the poet was doing was wanting to use the newer springy sense of the word *muelle*, which would be more recognizable with the older form *mollir (o→ue)* than with the modern *mullir* (at least it is for me), in addition to older words tending to sound more poetic.

As far as I know, this isn't a regionalism as the closest entry the *Diccionario de Americanismos* has is *amollar* which is definitively unrelated.

Comment: Just a guess, but I read muelle as the noun "spring" poetically used as a verb, possibly borrowing from the English verb.

Comment: So to get this straight, there are two versions: the old one, "mollir" (from Latin *mollire*), and the new one, "mullir". The former would be conjugated as "muelle", comparable to *dormir* > *duerme* or *morir* > *muere*; the latter would be conjugated as "mulle", comparable to *pulir* > *pule* or *bullir* > *bulle*. The author chose the old one both because it sounds archaic and therefore more poetic, and because coincidentally it's a homonym of the noun "muelle", creating a mental image of something sprinting. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Yay  not being the author I can't say with certainty why he chose that form, but that certainly is my hypothesis. That *muelle* is a form of *mollir*, though, is clear.

Comment: I see. What confuses me is that you say that "*mollir* (...) comes from *muelle*". Wouldn't it be the other way around (that is, *muelle* comes from *mollir*)?

Comment: @Yay Well, whether *mollis* or *mollire* came first, I don't know, I'm not a Latinist.  What I was trying to say is that the two words are related and thus despite the RAE not providing conjugations (it doesn't for old verbs), we can know that its *o* alternates/diphthongs to *ue* when stressed, something that won't happen with *mullir* (always u) or *mollear* (always *o*).  It's likely the OP looked at a site like http://conjugador.reverso.net/conjugacion-espanol-verbo-mollir.html and initially figured *mollir* couldn't be related to *muelle, but those conjugations are clearly wrong.

Comment: I checked "mollir" (unfortunately, I can't recall where now) and found the 3rd person singular form quoted as "molle". I did indeed wonder whether it could be a stem-changing verb like "dormir", but couldn't find any evidence. I'm glad you've supported my original hunch, guifa. Thanks also for your remark about the additional meaning of "spring", Jim Garrison. I didn't think that meaning could be coincidental, but it's good to have my hunch confirmed.